# Disabled left click in ajaxStatus

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I wanna disabled left click when `<p:ajaxStatus onstart="noClick();" 
            onsuccess="canClick();" />` start **p:ajaxSatus** and enabled click when success. Any idea?.
I´m working in Internet Explorer 7 and 8.
I use tipical **p:dataTable** with **cellEdit**

```
<p:dataTable id="tabla" value="#{BB.dataTable}" var="trm" resizableColumns="true"
    style="width : 1400px" editable="true" editMode="cell"
    rowStyleClass="#{styleController.daColoresParaEstadoTramos(trm)}">
<p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{BB.capturaTramo}" update="tabla2" />
</p:dataTable>
<p:blockUI block="tabla2" trigger="tabla2">  
    VERIFICANDO<br /> 
</p:blockUI>
```

Comment: Its bit hard to to understand what excatly you're after

Comment: don't you want to use primefaces block ui ? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/blockUI.jsf  define it to block some part of the screen and call it in your `p:ajaxStatus`

Comment: **p:blockUI** just works first time. Any idea??

Comment: @Makky I wanna disable click event when I do some validations in my BB and this finish activate click event.

Comment: Then comment from @Daniel is enough. That should work. If it doesn't then post your code.